# How to get rid of white highlight while typing on Visual Studio Mac

Tags: c#, visual-studio-mac

Highlighting I hate:

[image: image of a value being highlighting as I type]

This highlighting is useless to me; I know it is not a problem because I am in the middle of typing it out.

I have tried all the preferences. I am on a Mac and using the latest Visual Studio.

I don't care about the red underline; it is the white highlighting that contrast with my black background and makes it difficult to see. I have looked and can't find a way to remove this.

Comment: Just started up VS/Mac for the first time in a while and I think that's new - and I agree it's very annoying!

Comment: Updated to 17.6 Preview (17.6 build 1421) and it's gone away

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k2Qc.png

Comment: @stuartd Please post this as an answer, not a comment.